# /me/likes?limit=999 but it doesn't take all of them?

Tags: limit

I had a problem with user_likes who return only few likes but it was a FB limit (around 25)

I added "?limit=9999" :

```
addhobs($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=999'),$user->usersId);
```

It's working, take more likes but not all of them....

Any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: May it be due to pagination ?

Comment: pagination ? i don't know...

Comment: I thought yjis would send back a part of items and then links to get the following but I think I'm wrong. Have you tried FQL ?